# JavaScript - Get a values from all input fields and add that as a new person item in another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okey here is my code 
I have two divs

```
<div id="newPersonForm">
     <div class="formField">
         <form> 
           <div class="Nametxt smColor">
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input id="Name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="age smColor">
            <label for="age">Last age</label>
            <input id="age" type="number"/>
        </div>
         <button>Save</button>
         </form>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="ItemsHolder">
  <div class="items">
   <items goes here>
  </div>
</div>
```

And  a global array with some data inside

```
var defaultItems= [         
    {      
        name:"Bo",
        age:28,
        and many more objects inside properties here
    }
]
```

Now here  will be a `getValue()` function where I have variables representing inputs from the DOM

```
function getValue(){
  var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById('LastName').value;
```

Inside of this function I made another variable `person`, this will be an object, so the from the input values to go in this person object.

```
 var person = {
    name: name,
    lastName: lastName,
    defaultItems.push(person);
}
```

And lastly, I want the new person to be placed to the end of `defaultItems` array.

So here is what I want. The `defaultItems` array will contain default persons, with properties like `Name`, `Last Name`, `age` etc. They will be shown by default when the page loads. With the form, I want to register a new person, which contains the same inputs from `defaultItems`, and maybe some new. When I click save on the button, and go back in default page, I want that person from the form to appear next to the last defaults items.

It would be great if this could be done with native js, if possible.

Comment: Where do you want to save the persons data? You say, that you want to go back to default page -> this is a page reload. Either you will have a server side database or you use the local storage.

Comment: Sorry to mention, yes i want to save on Local Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the 'people' data being only available locally, than you can store each person object that is created from the input fields by the user into HTML5 local storage by doing something like:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    var person = { 'name': 'bill', 'age': '35'};
    defaultItems.push(person);
    localStorage.setItem('defaultItems', JSON.stringify(defaultItems));
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Then, whenever the page that you want the 'people' data to display on loads, use:

```
defaultItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defaultItems'));
```

and then iterate through the defaultItems array to display each person's info on the DOM.

If need your data to be available more than just on your own computer, you will need to store the 'people' data into a server database such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) (or something with similar capabilities).

---

**EDIT**:

A possible way to populate the DOM with all the people in the **defaultItems** array with native js:

```
var items = document.getElementByClass("items");
for(item in defaultItems) {
    items.innerHTML += "<div class='person'>";
    items.innerHTML += "<span>"+item.firstName+"</span>";
    items.innerHTML += "<span>"+item.lastName+"</span>";
    items.innerHTML += "<span>"+item.jobTitle+"</span>";
    items.innerHTML += "</div>";
}
```

Comment: I already have function that  display each item in the  DOM, but not displaying all properties, only Name, Last Name and Job Title. So how do write defaultItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defaultItems'));
this inside it? Sorry i never done this before

Comment: Check the edit in the post and let me know if that helps

Comment: Great. I would greatly appreciate it if you could just click that check mark next to my post on the left-hand side if my post really did help you! That helps me gain more reputation around here ;) Thank you!